# Why is my HTML unordered list "list-style-image" not working?

Tags: html, css

I cannot figure out why my unordered list "list-style-image" is not working. Here is what I have:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#the-list li {
  margin: 2em 0;
}

#the-list li:first-child {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="#00800066" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path d="M10.5 8a2.5 2.5 0 1 1-5 0 2.5 2.5 0 0 1 5 0z"/><path d="M0 8s3-5.5 8-5.5S16 8 16 8s-3 5.5-8 5.5S0 8 0 8zm8 3.5a3.5 3.5 0 1 0 0-7 3.5 3.5 0 0 0 0 7z"/></svg>');
}

#the-list li:last-child {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="#B2222266" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path d="m10.79 12.912-1.614-1.615a3.5 3.5 0 0 1-4.474-4.474l-2.06-2.06C.938 6.278 0 8 0 8s3 5.5 8 5.5a7.029 7.029 0 0 0 2.79-.588zM5.21 3.088A7.028 7.028 0 0 1 8 2.5c5 0 8 5.5 8 5.5s-.939 1.721-2.641 3.238l-2.062-2.062a3.5 3.5 0 0 0-4.474-4.474L5.21 3.089z"/><path d="M5.525 7.646a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 2.829 2.829l-2.83-2.829zm4.95.708-2.829-2.83a2.5 2.5 0 0 1 2.829 2.829zm3.171 6-12-12 .708-.708 12 12-.708.708z"/></svg>');
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    <ul id="the-list">
      <li>FIRST ... <span>word</span></li>
      <li>LAST ... <span>word</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: @j08691 The list image "bullet" should be the SVG image of an eye. normal eye for the first bullet and crossed out eye for the last bullet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to replace `#` with `%23` in your SVGs:

```css
  html,
  body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#the-list li {
  margin: 2em 0;
}

#the-list li:first-child {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="%2300800066" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path d="M10.5 8a2.5 2.5 0 1 1-5 0 2.5 2.5 0 0 1 5 0z"/><path d="M0 8s3-5.5 8-5.5S16 8 16 8s-3 5.5-8 5.5S0 8 0 8zm8 3.5a3.5 3.5 0 1 0 0-7 3.5 3.5 0 0 0 0 7z"/></svg>');
}

#the-list li:last-child {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="%23B2222266" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path d="m10.79 12.912-1.614-1.615a3.5 3.5 0 0 1-4.474-4.474l-2.06-2.06C.938 6.278 0 8 0 8s3 5.5 8 5.5a7.029 7.029 0 0 0 2.79-.588zM5.21 3.088A7.028 7.028 0 0 1 8 2.5c5 0 8 5.5 8 5.5s-.939 1.721-2.641 3.238l-2.062-2.062a3.5 3.5 0 0 0-4.474-4.474L5.21 3.089z"/><path d="M5.525 7.646a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 2.829 2.829l-2.83-2.829zm4.95.708-2.829-2.83a2.5 2.5 0 0 1 2.829 2.829zm3.171 6-12-12 .708-.708 12 12-.708.708z"/></svg>');
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    <ul id="the-list">
      <li>FIRST ... <span>word</span></li>
      <li>LAST ... <span>word</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works once Base64 encoded

```
html,
 body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   font-family: sans-serif;
 }

 #the-list li {
   margin: 2em 0;
 }

 #the-list li:first-child {
   color: red;
   font-weight: bold;
   list-style-type: none;
   list-style-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0naHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmcnIHdpZHRoPScxNicgaGVpZ2h0PScxNicgZmlsbD0nIzAwODAwMDY2JyB2aWV3Qm94PScwIDAgMTYgMTYnPjxwYXRoIGQ9J00xMC41IDhhMi41IDIuNSAwIDEgMS01IDAgMi41IDIuNSAwIDAgMSA1IDB6Jy8+PHBhdGggZD0nTTAgOHMzLTUuNSA4LTUuNVMxNiA4IDE2IDhzLTMgNS41LTggNS41UzAgOCAwIDh6bTggMy41YTMuNSAzLjUgMCAxIDAgMC03IDMuNSAzLjUgMCAwIDAgMCA3eicvPjwvc3ZnPg==");
 }
 #the-list li:last-child { 
     color: blue;
     font-weight: bold;
     list-style-type: none;
     list-style-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"); 
}
```